# Python iterator for binary search tree i.e. how does yield work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement an iterator for a BST, and I've done so for Lists, Heaps, etc. before. My confusion is regarding the use of yield.

In the code below, we are doing an inorder iteration. The code appears to first generate the keys from the left subtree and yield them, then yield the key of the root, and then generate and yield keys for the right subtree. However, why do we call 'yield node' for the subtrees whereas we call 'yield self.key' for the root? How does the iterator access keys from the left and right subtrees?

My instinct is that the iterator is implemented recursively, and it is only the base case where a node yields its key. The other calls to yield (as in 'yield node') simply seem to pass on the values from the base case. Could someone explain what is going on here?

P.S. Apologies for any incorrect use of pythonic jargon. I'm coming from a C++ background and still not totally comfortable and fluent with pythonic ways.

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self, key, val, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
            self.key = key
            self.value = val
            self.left_child = left
            self.right_child = right
            self.parent = parent

        ...

        def __iter__(self):
            if self:
                if self.left_child:
                    for node in self.left_child:
                        yield node
                yield self.key
                if self.right_child:
                    for node in self.right_child:
                        yield node

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.root.__iter__()
```

Comment: How is the tree constructed?

Comment: It is implicitely recursive, because it calls `__iter__` on `self.left_child`, which is presumably a `TreeNode`.

Comment: As an aside, nested classes like this are really not a common idiom in Python, and honestly, just make reading your class definitions confusing/annoying...

Comment: The thing that is confusing you is that it is using the variable name `node`, It should really be `for key in self.left_node:`, basically, if you keep recursing down, it will eventually not have anywhere to recurse on the left, and will simply give you `yield self.key`.